# How to start logstash via systemctl on CentOS7

Tags: logstash

I have been able to start `logstash` without issues using this command:

```
nohup /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f logstash.conf &
```

I have tried putting the `logstash` config file in `/etc`, then in `/etc/logstash` and it is of course in `/etc/logstash/conf.d` , all these various approaches did not help me start `logstash` via `systemctl`.

Comment: Is there a file `/etc/init.d/logstash` created when you installed `logstash`?

Comment: yes, and I am not able to figure out how JAVA_HOME is to be set in that file, I think that is the reason "/etc/init.d/logstash start" fails

Comment: Having said that when I start it using the cli, I don't pass JAVA_HOME either, has to be something else.....

Comment: Can you post the  `/etc/init.d/logstash` file in your question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KnxeLspu

Comment: Can you give more details as in what fails? or what error you get? What do you get when you check status? What is in your Logstash log files? Please mention these details in your question.

Comment: Yes, not much by way of log files etc. The command /etc/init.d/logstash start works and logstash starts fine but it is not reading any configuration file and not sending logs to ES. in a ps -ef | grep logstash shows "agent -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/"

Comment: and if I run logstash via the command line: /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf &, then I see the logs in ES and a ps -ef | grep logstash, shows "<snip>agent -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf"

Comment: Some more information: http://pastebin.com/3dWfBbJj